# How to search through the array and output answer in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, output

I am new to javascript and I am making a website in html.

I made the website header and put there form type of text input and a submit type of button next to it.

What I wanna do is when I put something in the search box and press submit, 
I want it to output me the results of the function that I am going to be using in the body of html.

The code I have got so far is:

```
var button = document.getElementById("button");

var data = ["Jaws, Jaws 1, Jaws 2, Jaws 3, Space Jame, Big Fish, The illusionit"];

button.onclick = function() {
var formInput = document.getElementById(formInput).value;
for (i=0; i<data.length;i++){
    if(data[i].indexOf(formInput) != -1) {
        alert(data[i]);
    }
    else {
        alert("We do not have any data like that. Sorry!");
    }
};
```

This is java script code and this is my hmtl code:

```
<body>
<div id="head">
    <div id="logo">
        <img src="img/logo.png" style="height:50px;">
    </div>
    <div id="search">
        <form>
            <input type="text" name="search"   class="search" id="formInput">
            <input type="submit" value="OK"    class="button" id="button">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="output">
    <script>
    var html = "The outputs are going to be: "
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = html;
    </script>
</div>
<div id="footer">
</div>
```

So if I input Jaws for example, I want it to give me back Jaws , Jaws 1, Jaws 2, Jaws 3

This is not working can anyone suggest how to make it work?
I know that I could be using php or some other language but I wanna do it with javascript and html only

Thanks!!!

Comment: Look up how to create arrays of strings in JavaScript. Your array currently has a single element, a very long string, instead of multiple string elements.

Comment: I'd also consider learning to use a library like jQuery rather than using native Javascript alone. This will make event handling easier and more compatible across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** to get filtered data

Try like this

```
var formInput = document.getElementById(formInput).value;
var dataList=data.filter(function(x){ return x.indexOf(formInput)>-1; });
for (i=0; i<dataList.length;i++){
  console.log(dataList[i]);
}
```

Your array doesn look good to me

Try to keep your array like this

```
var data = ["Jaws","Jaws 1","Jaws 2","Jaws 3","Space Jame","Big Fish","The illusionit"];
```

instead of

```
var data = ["Jaws, Jaws 1, Jaws 2, Jaws 3, Space Jame, Big Fish, The illusionit"];
```

Comment: I changed it the way you told me to do it, but it does not appear there. Is there anything that I should be calling in html file to make it work?

Comment: @comp can you provide fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var array = ["a","b","c"];
function searchIT(){
  var inputVal = document.getElementById("inputTxt").value;
  console.log(inputVal);
  if(array.indexOf(inputVal) !== -1){
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "The output is : "+ inputVal;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "There is no such element";
  }
}
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="inputTxt">
  <button onclick="searchIT();">Search</button>
<div id="result">
</div>
```